# Where to find proper documentation of Google Drive API Python client library

Tags: google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I want to use Google's Python client libraries to access the Google Drive API (v3). There is a [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) document that shows the basic usage of some of Google's Python packages, but I cannot find a proper, complete documentation anywhere. Where do I need to look?

In particular, the quickstart document contains the following Python code:

```python
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

...

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])
```

How do I know what methods and properties the `service` object has? This a complete blackbox to the user and I cannot find comprehensive documentation anywhere. PyCharm just sees `service` as an object of type `Any` and thus doesn't help me understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the `googleapiclient.discovery` module can be found here: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/index.html

To see what methods and properties the service object has, you can use Python's built-in `dir()` function. For example:

```
print(dir(service))
```

You can also use the built-in `help()` function to get more information about a specific method or attribute. For example:

```
help(service.files().list)
```